# Mikrotik L2TP server. Маршрутизация

Tags: vpn, route, mikrotik, l2tp

Имеем несколько подключений из разных локальных сетей в разных офисах к L2TP Server на Mikrotik, каждая из которых имеет адресный диапазон 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.5.0/24. Имеются так же сети 192.168.3.0/16 и, например, 192.168.222.0/16. За L2TP Server'ом так же имеется одна физическая локальная сеть, с разными адресными пространствами: например, та же 192.168.5.0/24. Как настроить так, чтобы соединенные L2TP VPN'ом подсети "видели" друг-друга?

Да, кстати, на стороне клиента сетей с адресным пространством 192.168.0.0/24 может быть несколько.

Как лучше организовать маршрутизацию?
Благодарю за любые подсказки.

Comment: Цель глобальная какая? Использовать l2tp для объединения офисов - плохая идея. Посмотрите в сторону IPsec (peer-to-peer) А вообще нужно в Вашем случае маршруты прописывать...

Comment: Для доступа к некоторым сервисам между офисами. Ок, а как, если не L2TP? И как именно прописывать машруты? Можно какие-нибудь примеры?

Comment: Я же сказал - IPsec. Все инструкции есть на сайте Mikrotik в разделе Wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На каждом клиенте который подключается к L2TP серверу дописать маршрут:

```
/ip route add dst-address=192.168.0.0/16 gateway=дальний конец тунеля L2TP-сервера.
```

на L2TP-сервере надо статически прописать маршруты в удаленные сети

```
/ip route add dst-address=192.168.x.0/24 gateway=дальний конец тунеля L2TP-клиента.
```

Answer (score -1):

В идеале лучше привести сети в порядок, но если нет такой возможности то поможет NAT конкретно netmap

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=11.11.11.0/24 \
    action=netmap to-addresses=2.2.2.0/24
```

Данное правило изменит адрес назначения в пакете (например) с адрес 11.11.11.50 на адрес 2.2.2.50

192.168.0.0/24---Router A ---L2TP или GRE ---Router B---192.168.0.0/24

Задача подключиться на адрес 192.168.0.10 за роутером B из сети за роутером А.

Router B

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=11.11.11.0/24 \
        action=netmap to-addresses=192.168.0.0/24
```

Router A

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat out-interface=vpntunnel \
        dst-address=11.11.11.0/24 action=src-nat to-address=x.x.x.x

/ip route add dst-address=11.11.11.0/24 gateway=y.y.y.y

x.x.x.x - Адрес на конце тоннеля роутера A
y.y.y.y - Адрес на конце тоннеля роутера B
vpntunnel - Имя интерфейса тоннеля (L2TP или GRE)
```

Сам не проверял) Но в теории должно работать.